# How to change Crystal Report font Dynamically using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with crystal report 13.0.12.1494. In My Project I have a Crystal Report With fields from database (SQL Server as Database). I am storing reference to font in project settings and want to replace font according to user preference from project settings 
for e.g. crystal report built with font arial, 10pt and user chooses times new roman, 12pt at runtime then report should be shown in times new roman, 12pt.

I tried Following without success

```
Dim myparam As New ParameterField
Dim myDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
myparam.ParameterFieldName = "My Parameter"
myDiscreteValue.Value = My.Settings.MyFont.Name
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the c# i used to change dynamically the font of my object.

The text object can be `TextObject` ( simple text ) or `FieldObject` ( from db )

```
 public static void ApplyFontAllText(ReportDocument rapport, Font style)
    {

        foreach (ReportObject obj in rapport.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects)
        {
            if (obj.GetType().Name.Equals("TextObject"))
            {

              ((TextObject)obj).ApplyFont(style);

            }
            else if (obj.GetType().Name.Equals("FieldObject"))
            {
                ((FieldObject)obj).ApplyFont(style);
            }
        }
    }
```

The both class have a `ApplyFont` method.
You can parse your font and then use `ApplyFont`.

Answer (score 1):

VB version:

```
Dim templatefont As Font

'scan all report objects in the crystal report _reportDoc
For Each x As ReportObject In _reportDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects
  'just change the font family. Keep styling (e.g. bold) same
  If x.GetType.Name.Equals("TextObject") Then
     templatefont = DirectCast(x, TextObject).Font
     DirectCast(x, TextObject).ApplyFont(New Font("Arial Unicode MS", templatefont.Size, templatefont.Style, templatefont.Unit))
  End If

  If x.GetType.Name.Equals("FieldObject") Then
     templatefont = DirectCast(x, FieldObject).Font
     DirectCast(x, FieldObject).ApplyFont(New Font("Arial Unicode MS", templatefont.Size, templatefont.Style, templatefont.Unit))         
  End If
Next
```